# Case insensitive search not working with special characters MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my user authentication I allow users to enter case insensitive `email`. Recently I saw in the logs that one user can not authenticate himself. Reason is because his `email` address has `+` character inside, and for some reason MongoDB case insensitive search can not find email with special characters. It's like the special characters are ignored when performing the regex search.

I created this testing example: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sAqSgch9KaN)

What is the reason of this behavior and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without `$regex`, with `aggregate`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          { "$toLower": "$email" },
          { "$toLower": "EXAMPLE+@gmail.com" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TaYRrgLWwLD)

Yet, if someone have solution with `$regex`, I would like to see that.

Answer (score 0):

If your users email have regex special characters like `+,.,(,[` etc
You can escape them before searching else MongoDB will think you mean the regex special character

Javascript code (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex))

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); 
}
```

With the above function `+` would become `\\+` and you could search like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UHgWbYtfNDw)

I am not sure i understanded but i think you need this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do a "double"-escape:

```
db.collection.find({
  email: {
    "$regex": "Example\\+?@gmail.com",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

Applied to your example it will now match both entries: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LMSCtjB-k7

Comment: @OP: Any feedback?